# How to source anaconda in Visual Studio Code (To select python interpreter)

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am brand new to VS Code and struggling to get my current py interpreter to run.
My current python interpreter is run off of sourcing anaconda and opening python
`source anaconda`
How to do I force VS Code to first source anaconda before looking for py interpreters?

(Anaconda is located on a linux server.)

Comment: are you on windows, linux, or macos ?

Comment: Local machine is windows,  working on a RHEL server via SSH

Answer (score 0):

Like a fool I Missed it in the docs. Just need to manually add the full path to python.

Command Palette > Preferences: Open User Settings > Then set python.pythonPath to (your required path). Reload VS Code and now the added path will be part of the Python Interpreters list.

Quick way to get path, 
 Source and Open Python in terminal and enter:
`$ where python`

Comment: The Python extension will also look for created Anaconda environments where a Python interpreter version was specified, so you shouldn't have to manually set the "python.pythonPath" if you created your environment that way.